# How to create a first derivative calculated column in spotfire

Tags: calculated-columns, spotfire

I am trying to use calculated columns in Spotfire to calculate the first derivative (x,y)for individual time series IDs (Z)

My data looks like this,

```
x,y,z
0,0,A
1,1,A
2,1.5,A
3,1,A
4,1,A
5,.9,A
6,.5,A
7,.1,A
8,1.1,A
9,11,A
1,1,B
2,1.5,B
3,1,B
4,1,B
5,.9,B
6,.5,B
7,.1,B
8,1.1,B
9,11,B
10,12,B
```

I was using this:

```
([y] - Min([y]) OVER (Previous([x])))
/ 
([x] - Min([x]) OVER (Previous([x])))
```

but (1) it doesn't seem right; and (2) how do i then do this OVER every [Z]

Comment: Are you taking the first derivative to be (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1) where x1 and y1 are the row before x2 and y2? Also, what version of Spotfire are you using? (new versions may have a built-in function that would be helpful here)

Comment: it would be very helpful if you also included a column of your expected results. I'm not sure I completely understand your approach but this would in/validate my understanding :)

Comment: @AndrewPruet, Yes that is what I'm doing, I definitely see a little error I was making. I am using 7.8, I've been waiting to get Spotfire X due to several tools built in to version 7.

Comment: @niko, good point let me add something!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

([y] - min([y]) Over (Intersect([z],Previous([x])))) / ([x] - min([x]) Over (Intersect([z],Previous([x]))))

however the first point is going to be blank for each z, and it might not be very stable if your data has lots of oscillations. For more sophisticated options, you could look into splines (see a number of SO answers) and using a TERR function (not data function, the functions starting with TERR_ if they are available to you) for the calculated column.

Gaia